# Как реализовать у бота процесс поиска и выдачу результатов в всплывающем окне

Tags: php, telegram-bot

К примеру при вводе в строку сообщения @vote , этот бот проводит у себя поиск и в всплывающем окне выдает результаты поиска для постинга.

Какими меодами реализован данный функционал? Подскажите, пожалуйста, хотя бы куда копать.

Answer (score 0):

Копать ясно куда - в сторону [официальной документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). То, о чём Вы спрашиваете, есть [Inline Bots](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline). **Включаете своему боту [inline mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode) и реализуете логику запросов и ответов**. Всё.